# The Bearer token authentication in Azure API Management

Tags: azure-api-management

I am having an API in Azure API Management which requires the Bearer token authentication.
The tricky thing is that currently we can't use standard JWT bearer token as Client Credentials flow grant type is only preview.

That's why the idea is to send Subscription generated in APIM to satisfy API authentication requirements in the following format:

```
Authorization : Bearer <subscription key>
```

where `<subscription key>` is not in JWT format.

Is it there any way to handle this scenario where bearer token is a Subscription generated in APIM?

Answer (score 1):

**Generate a subscription key in APIM:**  go to the APIM portal and click on the "Subscriptions" tab, click on the Add subscription button to create new subscription. while creating the subscription key, you can add it to your all the APIs/single API/Product as per the scope.

[image]

- Copy the subscription key by clicking three dots present at the extreme right and then click on the show/hide key option.

[image]

**Configure the subscription key in the Inbound policy:** In the APIM portal, go to the API's "Inbound policy" tab and select "Add policy".

[image]

- Choose the `"set-header"` policy and set the `"Name" to "Authorization"` and the `"Value" to "Bearer {your subscription key}"`.

[image]

[image]

**Test the API:**

- You can test the API by sending a request with the subscription key as the bearer token in the "Authorization" header. The request should include the below header: `Authorization: Bearer <subscription key>`.

[image]

[image]